# Wordpress Plugin : Can't process Indexing Queue

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I'm trying to use the Wordpress plugin, but when I select tables, press save, they stay in the Queue and I can't click on the "Process Queue" Button.
I've tried to deactivate and reactivate the plugin. What can i do? I'm using Wordpress 4.6.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there,
The queue should get processed automatically without the need to hit the process queue button. Could you check the "logs" page and tell us if you have errors there? Also do you have PHP errors when WP_DEBUG is turned on? Lats question, what version of the Algolia Search plugin for WordPress are you using?

Comment: Hey (salut!); I don't get any errors in the logs page. I'm using the latest version of the plugin that I downloaded yesterday on GitHub. 

I alternatively get "Task Queue status: Idle" and "Task Queue status: Running Idle", but the "Task Queue pending tasks" stays the same (5 in my case). 

I turned on WP Debug but couldn't see any errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Salut salut, I have updated the docs that lacked one variable: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/logs.html#php-logs
could you make sure WP_DEBUG_LOG is also defined to true and try it again to see the errors in the wp-content/debug.log file?

Comment: Hey, just tried that but no debug log appears, and I still can't index my tables.

Comment: If i inspect the button element "process queue", there doesn"t seem to be any link.

<span class="run-queue-link">
      | <a href="#" class="page-title-action algolia-run-queue">Process queue</a>
     </span>

Comment: Could you give us the list of plugins you are using? Did you try disabling some of them to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Hey, sorry I was away. Here's a complete list of my plugins (I tried to deactivate W3TotalCache and downloading the newest update for the plugin, but still can't launch indexation).
LayerSlider WP  
Share Buttons 
Akismet   
Algolia Search   
BackWPup
Better Delete Revision
CMS Tree Page View 
Contact Form 7
Cookie Notice   
Duplicate Post  
Fusion Core  
Regenerate Thumbnails 
Search shortcode  
WP woocommerce
Sucuri Security - Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening   by Sucuri, INC
WooCommerce
Yoast SEO
Easy External Links   
Yet Another Stars Rating

Comment: I also just tried on a different website that i created last week - still doesn't work. It uses the same plugins, more or less.
Both websites hosted on OVH.com and running the Avada Theme

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372772/algolia-wordpress-plugin-wont-process-index-cueue? The server must be reachable through http, so for me the error was that I was using password protection on the site through WPEngine.

Answer (score 0):

We just released a new version of the plugin 1.2.0: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/

You can now install the plugin directly from the admin of WordPress from the 'plugins' section.

It appears OVH is using an old version of the cURL library, and that it fails validating some SSL certificates which makes calls fail.

If your website is reachable over HTTP, you could add the following line to your wp-config.php file `define('ALGOLIA_LOOPBACK_HTTP', true);`.

I've seen this succeed in other OVH environments. Could you give it a try?