# Algolia WordPress Plugin Wont Process Index Cueue

Tags: wordpress, algolia

In reference to the following existing question. [Wordpress Plugin : Can't process Indexing Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310765/wordpress-plugin-cant-process-indexing-queue/39356327#39356327) I was unable to participate in the comments due to having a new account and less than 50 reputation.

I am having a problem getting the Algolia WordPress plugin to process the index. Running the latest version of WP and just downwloaded the WP Plugin from Algolia today. When I run WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG in my wp-config file I get the following output on any WP back end page.

has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /var/www/html/dealer/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3890

Line 3890 in wp-includes/functions.php just references the code that generated the error.

`trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! %3$s'), $function, $version, $message ) );`

This appears to be an unrelated issue.

I should point out that this is a dev test server running locally on our internal network. I'm starting to wonder if that's causing the issue. I installed the same plugin on our live version of the site and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

We have never noticed any logs related to user capabilities. Your best bet to remove those notices is to:

- Be sure all your plugins are updated,
- Disable/Test/Enable plugins one by one to locate the plugin raising those.

Please ensure that all the requirements are met: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/installation.html

Do you have any errors logged on the "Logs" page of the Algolia plugin?
Might be useful to also give us the list of plugins you are using.

Comment: It's not a conflict with another plugin. As I already stated, this is running on an internal test server that is an exact copy of a live site. The plugin works fine on the live site but not the internal server. The only entries on the logs page are for index items being added to the queue. But they are never processed and the process queue button is always present but does nothing when I click on it. Same issue as the question I referenced above.

Comment: Hi Reverie, 
For the task queue to work, it must be able to access the server over http. Can you confirm that you have updated your urls to match your local configuration?

Comment: It would be nice if this could be added to the installation requirements, as indexing will not work on WPEngine's password protected sites for instance.

Comment: You are 100% right @BenedicteRaae I added this as an additional requirement: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/pull/264/files

We eventually will implement a way for you to provide the credentials so that we can work around the protection.

Comment: Good addition, easy to understand @rayrutjes.